# What is the difference between declaring connection via object tag and Server.CreateObject

Tags: asp-classic, createobject

When using classic ASP, what is the difference between declaring connection via object tag:

```
<object RUNAT="Server" ID="cn" PROGID="ADODB.Connection"></object>
```

and declaring the connection via the Server.CreateObject() call:

```
set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

Or is there any difference?  Performance, memory, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object method should perform better, because the object is first created when you start using it.

I found some articles, maybe they give you some insight:

http://www.aspmessageboard.com/showthread.php?t=6775

http://www.asp101.com/tips/index.asp?id=4